# How to know if graceful restart / stop was executed?

Tags: asterisk

Is there a way to know if `restart gracefully` or `stop gracefully` has been executed on asterisk while still running and waiting for calls to end then, restart/stop?

When this mode is executed, Asterisk will stop receiving new calls and will output "Channel allocation failed: Refusing due to active shutdown", but besides this, how do I know if this mode is triggered?

I am not asking how to know if it is stopped or not. I am asking how, while asterisk is still running and in this "gracefull state", to know if this "state" is ON or OFF.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the log files for the following message(s) in order to determine if the command was issued gracefully:

```
Waiting for inactivity to perform shutdown
Waiting for inactivity to perform restart
```

Source: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/asterisk/main/asterisk.c#can_safely_quit